# Marionette AppRouter, unable to navigate to the proper URL

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, marionette

I'm going through examples with routing from David Sulc's book Backbone.Marionette.js: A Gentle Introduction

https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction

```
ContactManager.navigate = function (route, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    Backbone.history.navigate(route, options);

};


ContactManager.getCurrentRoute = function () {
    return Backbone.history.fragment;
};


ContactManager.on("initialize:after", function () {

    if (Backbone.history) {
        Backbone.history.start();

        if (this.getCurrentRoute() === "") {
            ContactManager.trigger("contacts:list");

        }

    }
```

As you can see if the history fragment is empty, it will trigger the contacts:list event which will render the list of contacts. However, it doesn't redirect at all, and I've found out that fragment is preset to "contacts" somehow, so the event doesn't get fired at all. It also happened to me once that initially the fragment was empty and got everything rendered, and url changed properly, but upon refresh fragment was still "contacts" and again nothing was rendered.

```
 ContactsApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        AppRoutes: {
            "contacts": "listContacts"

        }
    });

ContactManager.on("contacts:list", function () {
        ContactManager.navigate("contacts");
        API.listContacts();

    });
```

This is the code that handles the event. What seems to be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: has my answer helped solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears I had an error elsewhere in the code and successfully debugged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some missing code. I would expect to find something like this in the router:

```
var myController = {
    listContacts: function () {
        ContactManager.trigger("contacts:list");
    }
};

ContactsApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    controller: myController,
    appRoutes: {
        "contacts": "listContacts"
    }
});
```

Note that `appRoutes` starts with a lowercase a.

Now the route `contacts` will call the controller's `listContacts` method and trigger the `ContactManager.on("contacts:list"...` callback, running the appropriate API method.